# How can I run powershell.exe with Anaconda in new windows terminal profiles?

Tags: json, windows, powershell, anaconda

New Windows Terminal (Windows Terminal (Preview) Version: 0.2.1831.0) have settings in JSON file. How can I setup powershell running with Anaconda?
Anaconda running in powershell with:

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\akali\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\akali\Anaconda3' "
```

Windows Terminal use profiles in JSON like this:

```
  "profiles": [{
       "colorScheme": "Solarized Light",
       "commandline": "powershell.exe"
   }]
```

How can I use running with Args with double quote in JSON that allow me run something like `-Command "& 'C:\'"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I realize I'm late of some years but I had a similar problem and stranded up here looking for an answer. So, I'm hoping that this is useful for people like me in the future.

After some time tinkering I generated an Anaconda profile:

- copy paste an existing profile
- [generate guid here](http://new-guid.com/)
- open C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)
- right click on Anaconda Powershell Prompt (Miniconda3) and go to Properties
- copy the entire content of the `target` field and paste it on the field `commandline` (make sure the field is `commandline` and not `source`)
- escape all the `\` characters  (`\` --> `\\`)
- Change the name field

You should have something like this

```
{
        "guid": "{generated guid}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Anaconda",
        "commandline": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command & 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3'"
        
    },
```

As a nice sidenote, you can also create a profile to directly launch an Ipython session or a jupyter notebook.
As you may have noticed, lo launch anaconda in the `commandline` field we are just launching `powershell.exe`, and then telling the powershell instance to execute a `-Command`, which is the subsequent string.
Were you to add a `; ipython` to the command, you would launch an ipython session.

Comment: A new GUID can also be generated using the `New-Guid` command in PowerShell.

Comment: It also works if you remove all the extra single quotation marks:   

`"commandline": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command & C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda activate C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3"`

Comment: @Marco Necci I know showing gratitude in comments in frowned upon but I have to say Thank You So Much ! for adding your fix -- I've been trying to figure this out for months!

Answer (score 2):

- Copy-paste the settings for cmd from above.
- Go to "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)"
- Right-click on "Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)"
- Copy the content from the target field and paste it on the field commandline

  Mine is `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\bin\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\bin\Anaconda3`
- Replace \ with \
- Thanks to the above answer by Marco Necci, this is a more clear version with cmd and anaconda

  `"commandline" : "%windir%\\System32\\cmd.exe /K C:\\bin\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\bin\\Anaconda3"`

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Navaneeth M et al, I contribute a command line which includes the default Anaconda location using USERPROFILE environment variable, specifying non-default Anaconda env (fastai), starting directory and color scheme.

```
"commandline": "%windir%\\System32\\cmd.exe /K %USERPROFILE%\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat fastai",
"colorscheme": "Solarized Light",
"startingDirectory": "c:\\sw",
```

Pro Tip: Use `keybindings` to add a hotkey which opens a new tab in the specified project directory. For example, use ctrl-b to open a new Anaconda tab in just the right place.

```
"keybindings": [
  {
    "keys": [ "ctrl+b" ],
    "command": {
      "action": "newTab",
      "profile": "Anaconda",
      "startingDirectory": "c:\\sw\\myproject\\myprojectdirectory"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click properties of conda powershell shortcut (in desktop or start menu). There you get the path to the command that effectively starts conda using powershell.

Now, just follow the recipe of Marco Necci [outlined above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314547/5591870), just caring to put double backslashes instead of single ones.

Searching further modifications, in [this site](https://traviscolbert.net/blog/windows-terminal-generating-guids-for-your-profiles/) i've found that i could generate the new needed [guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#unique-identifier) with powershell itself:  `[guid]::NewGuid()`.

And in the [repo of new terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/user-docs/ThirdPartyToolProfiles.md#adding-profiles-for-third-party-tools), i've discovered it's possible to customize the icon too. My icon was in a different path, that i came across looking in anaconda shortcut in windows menu (i used anaconda navigator's icon - right click it > more > open; somewhere ending with 'Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)': right click once more in the shortcut > properties; change icon - there is the path to the icon).

Again, be wary to use double backslashes instead of single ones.